# can't able to connect to socket.io in Node JS using web storm IDE

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, webstorm

I am new to node js and trying to connect my app to sockets. I have created socket in bin/www, my setting is initialized in app.js. I am using routes to access my views.

I was to access socket using io.on() in chat.js file but I am getting error. Kindly give me the way to access chat.ejs with

**bin/www**

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('jetbrains first app:server');
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io');

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
var socket = io.listen(server);

socket.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("socket created in WWW");
    socket.emit('data', {message : 'hello world'});
    socket.on('new',function(data){
        console.log(data.mess);
    });
});

console.log("Server is listening on port: " + port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

**app.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var chat = require('./routes/chat');

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/chat', chat);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});


if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

**routes/chat.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var io = require('socket.io');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    res.render('chat', {title: 'chat'});
    io.sockets.on('new',function(data){
        console.log("In chat.js "+data.mess);
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

I want to handle io like this so only chat.ejs and chat.js will be connected through sockets and only these two file will send eachother data.

**views/chat.ejs**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:>
    <head>
        <title>
            <%= title %>
        </title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
        <% include header.ejs %>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/chat');
            socket.on('data', function (data) {
                console.log(data.message);
                socket.emit('new', {mess: 'hello'});
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>
        <%= title %>
    </h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
    </br>

    Name:</br>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
    </br></br>
    message:</br>
    <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Enter Message">
    </br></br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">
    </body>
</html>
```

when doing this I am getting error "cant set header after being sent". complete log is.

```js
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (c:\Users\Khurram\Desktop\jetbrains first app\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.contentType (c:\Users\Khurram\Desktop\jetbrains first app\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:551:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (c:\Users\Khurram\Desktop\jetbrains first app\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:138:14)
    at done (c:\Users\Khurram\Desktop\jetbrains first app\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:957:10)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (c:\Users\Khurram\Desktop\jetbrains first app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:355:10)
    at View.render (c:\Users\Khurram\Desktop\jetbrains first app\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:126:8)
    at tryRender (c:\Users\Khurram\Desktop\jetbrains first app\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:639:10)
    at EventEmitter.render (c:\Users\Khurram\Desktop\jetbrains first app\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:591:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (c:\Users\Khurram\Desktop\jetbrains first app\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:961:7)
```

Comment: And what's the error ?

Comment: Muhammad, error messages aren't just jibberish spit out by the compiler for fun. Error messages ***actually mean something valuable***, and when you include them, experienced engineers can find the problem much faster. Please [edit] your post to include the error message.

Comment: just added the post and included the error details....